# 48 byte binary to 6 byte binary

Tags: c, binary, hex, arrays, byte

I read a 17 byte hex string from command line `"13:22:45:33:99:cd"` and want to convert it into binary value of length 6 bytes.

For this, I read a 17 byte hex string from command line `"13:22:45:33:99:cd"` and converted it into binary digits as  `0001 0011 0010 0010 0100 0101 0011 0011 1001 1001 1100 1101`. However, since I am using a char array, it is of length 48 bytes. I want the resulting binary to be of length 6 bytes i.e, I want `0001 0011 0010 0010 0100 0101 0011 0011 1001 1001 1100 1101` to be of 6 bytes (48 bits) and not 48 bytes. Please suggest how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *input = "13:22:45:33:99:cd";
int output[6];
unsigned char result[6];
if (6 == sscanf(input, "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",
                &output[0], &output[1], &output[2],
                &output[3], &output[4], &output[5])) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        result[i] = output[i];
} else {
    whine("something's wrong with the input!");
}
```

Comment: -1 Actually. This isn't right. First, `%x` is for `ints`, not `chars`. Second, `char` may be a signed type and therefore a value such as 0xFF will be outside of the range of `char`, causing signed overflow, which, in turn is undefined behavior.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze noticed that. fixed.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker why 6? why not 17?

Comment: @auselen, `scanf`-family functions return the number of items assigned, no?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker feel free to edit the post, I didn't get what you mean.

Comment: why is 'output' integer array? Pls help me understand.

Comment: btw I'm sure this is not what OP is asking in the first place, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772685/how-to-convert-mac-string-to-a-byte-address-in-c

Comment: @user1727270 because scanf with %x expects an integer pointer. if you pass byte/char it will overwrite something else.

Answer (score 3):

Split the string on the `':'` character, and each substring is now a string you can pass to e.g. [`strtoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul) and then put in a `unsigned char` array of size 6.

Answer (score 1):

You pack them together. Like high nibble with low nibble: `(hi<<4)|lo` (assuming both are 4-bits).

Although you may prefer to convert them byte by byte, not digit by digit in the first place.